# Tokens on Tezos

Tags: protocol

I'm interested in creating a token, similar to an ERC20 token on Ethereum, on the Tezos network. If I see correctly, as of now there is no possibility to track tokens on any of the public block explorers. Is this correct, and will that change? I found a token contract by Mr. Andrews, ꜩtoken, but I'm not sure in how far this will result in what I am looking for. Could you please shed some light on the state of tokens on Tezos and how to dive deeper into the topic? I heard tokenized real estate offerings are coming to the platform. What will that look like? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two token standards on Tezos worth considering [FA1.2](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-7/tzip-7.md) and [FA2](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md). There are already originated contracts for these on the Tezos mainnet. You can explore them at [Better Call Dev FA1.2](https://better-call.dev/stats/mainnet/fa12) and [Better Call Dev FA2](https://better-call.dev/stats/mainnet/fa2).